# Search through autocomplete rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

**JS:**

```
<script>

$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "NSDL",
      "CDSL",
      "ROCA",
      "NSE",
      "SEBI"      
    ];
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });

</script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

In `_index.js.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag service_requests_path, method: :get,:id=>"search_form" do %>  
<%= text_field_tag :search , nil, class: 'form-control input-breathe', required: true, placeholder: 'Searching for...', :autocomplete=> :on%><%end%>
```

I want to search with textbox only, without using any button.Now I am getting all the values from the textbox. But the problem is that, when I am selecting any of the tag, it should search all the service requests containing this tag. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add event listener to form so that whenever user select any tag, form should be automatically submitted.

```
var availableTags = [
  "NSDL",
  "CDSL",
  "ROCA",
  "NSE",
  "SEBI"      
];
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  select: function(event, ui){
        $('#search').val(ui.item.value)
        $('#search_form').submit()
  }
});
```

Jquery autocomplete plugin provide select callback which is called automatically whenever tag is selected. So submit your search form. I assume your search form has id os 'search_form'. Please replace it with id you applied to form.

Comment: Did you add id to your search form?